# How to get matched items count with $top in SharePoint REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013, caml

I am using SharePoint REST API. I am using post API to get the items `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listtitle)/getItems`. SharePoint GET Rest API has URL length limitation. Therefore we are using POST API to get the items.

We have list of 60k items with threshold limit of 70k. We are applying various AND and OR operations in CAML query and retrieving only first 200 items using $top clause. It is working fine and giving expected results.

With $top=200, getting length of result as 200 in ajax call's success method using data.d.results.length. Matching items of CAML query is 40k. If we do not apply $top, data.d.results.length is equal to 40k. We want this count(40k) when we use $top=200 items. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a contradiction!  "We want this count(40k) when we use $top=200 items."  Do you want the top 200 or top 40,000? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Mike Smith - MCT - MVP I want both. I want to return top 200 items and at the same time I want to know how many total number of items query going to return.

Comment: In Sharepoint Search API, we have option to provide StartRow and Rowlimit, at the same time we get the TotalRows in the response. I want to achieve similar thing here

Comment: Can't you just use the count of the objects returned?   data.d.results.length  Or are you looking for the total rows available in the list, in addition to the 200 items returned.

Comment: No, I am not looking for total rows in list which is 60k. data.d.results.length will give me 200 if I will use $top=200. I want 40k in data.d.results.length if I will use $top=200

Comment: In above scenario, if we use Sharepoint Search API and provide StartRow=0 and RowLimit=200, then in success method of ajax call we get 40k in TotalRows property